# Hide posts with specific categories term using filters everywhere

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to hide post with specific category for users not logged in and with not specific group i checked i tried to use this code but it doesnt work it hides my homepage content etc.`add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop', -1 );

```
function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a post or page.
    if ( is_single()) {
        if (has_term('categoryname', 'category')){
            if ( (is_user_logged_in() && $customer_group_id == $group_id) || is_admin() ) {
              return $content;
            }
              else
            {
              return $content ="". esc_html__("for specific users only", "my-textdomain");
            }
        }
        else{
         return $content;
        }
}
}`
```

ho to make the code work on archive blog page , single post and do not break homepage(page)

Comment: Do you want to replace the content as in the code above or hide the posts completely?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the "$content" parameter in that filter please try the below code.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop', 5, 1 );
function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a post or page.
    if ( is_single() ) { // check if this is single or archive of post.
        if ( has_term( 'categoryname', 'category' ) ){ // check specific category is include.
            if ( ( is_user_logged_in() && $customer_group_id == $group_id) || is_admin() ) { // your user logged in and group logic.
                return $content;
            }else{
                return $content ="". esc_html__("for specific users only", "my-textdomain");
            }
        }else{
            return $content;
        }
    }elseif ( is_category( 'categoryname' ) ) {
        if ( ( is_user_logged_in() && $customer_group_id == $group_id) || is_admin() ) { // your user logged in and group logic.
            return $content;
        }else{
            return $content ="". esc_html__("for specific users only", "my-textdomain");
        }   
    }else{
        return $content;    
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working on single page but on archive it shows excerpt

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. has_term function will not work on archive page.

Comment: Still on category page(archive) it shows part of text as an excerpt i want to hide it also on archive and category ..not only on single post

Comment: yes i used it and still showing main text as excerpt in blog view

Comment: ok i know what is the problem now code is working but when i visit general blog category and the "categoryname" is subcategory  i should see only content of posts which are not with this "categoryname" and now when i see still post content of all posts both in "categoryname" and others